# How can I highlight 25 minutes on an analogue clock using CSS gradients?

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry, linear-gradients

I'm trying to implement a countdown timer but on an analogue clock instead of a digital one. My goal is to highlight the next 25 minutes as a circle sector that starts from the minutes clock handle.

This is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/seifjo/pen/ExVQLOd

This is the relevant code from the above codepen:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #68a4ff;
}

.clock {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #bcd0e7;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.clock {
  background-image: url(clock.png), linear-gradient(330deg, transparent 50%, #fff 50%), linear-gradient(540deg, #fff 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.clock::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #848484;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
  position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #848484;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.mn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #d6d6d6;
  z-index: 11;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.sc:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ff6767;
  z-index: 12;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="hour">
    <div class="hr" id="hr">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="min">
    <div class="mn" id="mn">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
    <div class="sc" id="sc">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const deg = 6;
  const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
  const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
  const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
  setInterval(() => {
    let day = new Date();
    let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
    let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
    let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

    hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
    mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
    sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

I managed to highlight the next 25 minutes starting from 3 o'clock. But I can't figure out the relation between the minutes and the degrees. Eventually this will be a react app where I'll pass the current minute as a prop.

Comment: "starts from the minutes clock handle", im not quite getting this part. could you elaborate more?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski for example if the current time is 5:32AM and like to highlight the next 25 minutes from there so from 5:32 until 5:57.

Comment: will the highlighted sector move along the time passed? Or it stay at the sector at the time the page is opened

Comment: The second option (it stays the same) because once I figure out that part I can take it from there.

Comment: If the white part of the clock was a background image on its own div within the clock instead of on the clock, then you could just do the math and rotate that on init. Or the same with the color section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the highlight sector is w.r.t current time, I remove the style from css and calculate the style in script.

please note the solution only works for highlight period <= 30mins. Since the background image is a half circle. For more then 30mins, you need another second half circle and by controlling how many they overlap, you will highlight sector > 30mins

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #68a4ff;
}

.clock {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #bcd0e7;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.clock::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #848484;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
  position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #848484;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.mn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #d6d6d6;
  z-index: 11;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.sc:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ff6767;
  z-index: 12;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="hour">
    <div class="hr" id="hr">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="min">
    <div class="mn" id="mn">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
    <div class="sc" id="sc">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const deg = 6;
  const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
  const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
  const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
  setInterval(() => {
    let day = new Date();
    let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
    let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
    let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

    hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
    mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
    sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
  }, 1000);

  let lauchTime = new Date();
  let clock = document.querySelector('.clock');
  let startDeg = ((lauchTime.getMinutes() * deg) + 360 - 90) % 360;
  let highlightPeriod = 25;
  let endDeg = startDeg + (highlightPeriod * deg);

clock.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(${startDeg}deg, transparent 50%,  #fff 50%), linear-gradient(${endDeg}deg,  #fff 50%, transparent 50%)`;
</script>
```